# Running kubeadm join inside WSL2 with Zerotier VPN has problem with TLS handshake

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vpn, zerotier

I would like to run this wierd setup for my project that is: kubernetes cluster inside WSL2 with ZeroTier VPN. I have my Zerotier VPN setup and both computers are inside the network. Their assigned addreses are:

- control plane: 10.147.20.57
- worker node: 10.147.20.13

I can ping the machines and when I have nginx running inside wsl i can curl the nginx welcome page from other node just fine. I have mirroredNetworking=true inside .wslconfig so this allows to inherit Windows host network interfaces inside WSL2.

I can init cluster just fine. On control plane as root user inside wsl2:

```bash
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.147.20.57
```

on worker node as root user inside wsl2:

```bash
kubeadm join 10.147.20.57:6443 --token ... --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash ...
```

output:

```bash
...
preflight and validations passed
...
I0205 16:21:04.460968    1028 join.go:532] [preflight] Discovering cluster-info
I0205 16:21:04.460991    1028 token.go:80] [discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "10.147.20.57:6443"
I0205 16:21:04.461402    1028 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.29.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bc401b9" 'https://10.147.20.57:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s'
I0205 16:21:04.463526    1028 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:10.147.20.57:6443 succeed
I0205 16:21:14.462415    1028 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://10.147.20.57:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s  in 10000 milliseconds
I0205 16:21:14.462498    1028 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 2 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 10000 ms
I0205 16:21:14.462544    1028 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0205 16:21:14.462849    1028 token.go:217] [discovery] Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Get "https://10.147.20.57:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I0205 16:21:20.055607    1028 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.29.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bc401b9"
```

When i open https://10.147.20.57:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s in Chrome it says that its unsafe but when i click continue it displays cluster info.

Running nc works

```bash
root@node:/# nc -zv 10.147.20.57 6443
Connection to 10.147.20.57 6443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

I have turned off firewall on control plane in Windows and also inside WSL2 so i guess its not firewall issue.

But when I curl the address from terminal I get this:

```bash
root@node:/# curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.29.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bc401b9" 'https://10.147.20.57:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.147.20.57:6443...
* Connected to 10.147.20.57 (10.147.20.57) port 6443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to 10.147.20.57:6443
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to 10.147.20.57:6443
```

**I guess this is something to do with SSL Certificate authority of Kuberntetes + ZerortierVPN. Any help or pointing in right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!**

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! We're glad you're here. To get the most out of our community, please take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with our guidelines and expectations. Check out the quick [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the [section on 'on-topic' questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). By following these guidelines, you'll be well-equipped to ask effective questions and receive valuable assistance. Thanks for joining us!